# How to avoid upper limit of repetitions in loops when using float variables as iterators in GLSL?

Tags: gpu, glsl, shader

I'm making a simple fragment shader visualizer tool with OpenGL to easily display and work with GLSL fragment shaders. I'm making it in C using GLFW. Of course, my reference is [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) which I think is made with WebGL 2.0.

I'm getting weird behavior when trying to port shaders that use floating point variables as loop iterators, effectively limiting my loop count to two every time. The same shader executes as expected in shadertoy. If I use integers as iterators on the other hand, I get no issues and all repetitions execute as expected. My application manages to port any shadertoy shader that does not perform floating point loops successfully.

This [link](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/1012/msg00063.php) says float loops are supported in GLSL. Could it be that specifically the GLSL compiler I'm using limits these loops, when WebGL 2.0 does not? Or maybe there are options and / or OpenGL settings to prevent loops from being limited? Am I missing a flag that changes this behaviour?

I'm using #version 330 core as GLSL version.

It's all being tested on a MacBook Pro using MacOS with integrated Intel GPU. I know the hardware is able to perform floating point loops because I have no issues in shadertoy. Maybe WebGL and GLFW use different graphics drivers or OpenGL implementations on MacOS?

```
#define N 40.0

 void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord)
{
    float acc = 0.0, s = 1.0 / N;
    for (float n = 0.0; n < N; n++) {
        acc += s;
    }
    fragColor = vec4(acc, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This is the GLSL fragment shader I'm testing. When all loop repetitions are executed it should output a saturated red color in the entire screen. That's what happens in shadertoy, but in my application it produces a very dark red which is equivalent to the loop iterating only two times.

I've tried declaring and defining the iterator outside of the for loop, incrementing specifically by 1.0, using while loops and no luck. Only two iterations when using floats.

**UPDATE**

I tried retrieving the info log at compiling and linking steps and I got no message. Checked for error and status values and nothing. I actually found out even weirder behavior.

I found a way in which I'm able to iterate over two times using floats by using a very specific while loop syntax.

```
#define N 40.0

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord)
{
    float n = 0.0, acc = 0.0, s = 1.0 / N;
    while (n++ < N) {
        acc += s;
    }
    fragColor = vec4(acc, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Note that if I do `n++` in the body of the while loop instead, I get back to only two iterations. I find it very strange since it proves that my compiler is actually able to handle longer loops with floating point variables, but is just enabled with this very specific syntax. I've found no documentation on something like this and no way to specify compiler flags or hints. Could it be a compiler bug or missing feature?

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening is compiler incorrectly estimating maximum number of iterations possible.

OpenGL Shading Language Specification for version 3.3 explicitly states `Non-terminating loops are allowed. The consequences of very long or non-terminating loops are platform dependent.` (this is not unique for 3.3 version). Practically most GLSL compilers unroll loops, instead of actually looping, not supporting these "very long" loops. While your loop is not that long, floats might trick the compiler. In that case it most likely produces a warning, and you should check the compilation log, retrievable via `glGetShaderInfoLog` function.

If the problem is indeed related to incorrect unrolling, you can try some compiler specific hint on how many iterations it should expect. They are evil magic though, and are definetely not recommended.

Comment: in general it is not a good practice to use floating numbers in for loop iterators for possible infinite loops and precision issues.